# undefined offset error on previously echoed array?

Tags: php, arrays

I can't understand this behaviour, I have the following code inside a loop to identify whether the array has the "data" index inside. If it doesn't exists I try to identify previous array value, next array value and current array value, but the thing I can't not understand is that, the previous array displays a undefined offset error when it has been previously displayed correctly. This:

```
if(array_key_exists('data', $finalstrings[$y][$p]))
{
    echo $counter." - finalstring[".$y."][".$p."]['data'] = DATA: ".$finalstrings[$y][$p]['data']."<br />";
    $counter++;
}
else
{
    echo "Doesn't exists DATA in finalstring[".$y."][".$p."]['data']</br />";
    $index = $p-1;
    $index2 = $p+1;
    echo "Index: ".$index." - Index2: ".$index2."<br />";
    echo "PREV: ".$finalstring[$y][$index]['data']."</br />";
    echo "NEXT: ".$finalstring[$y][$index2]['data']."</br />";
    print_r($finalstring[$y][$p]);
    echo "<br />";  
}
```

OUTPUTS THIS:

```
478 - finalstring[11][72]['data'] = DATA: 554786242
Doesn't exists DATA in finalstring[11][73]['data']
Index: 72 - Index2: 74
Notice: Undefined offset: 11 in whatever/Info.php on line 134 PREV:
Notice: Undefined offset: 11 in whatever/Info.php on line 135 NEXT:
Notice: Undefined offset: 11 in whatever/Info.php on line 136
479 - finalstring[12][0]['data'] = DATA: 876547565
```

But `finalstring[11][72]` has been correctly displayed before...
What I'm missing?

Comment: You're missing an `s`: $finalstring**s**

Comment: In my htaccess I have "php_value error_reporting 8191" any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The corrent array name is `$finalstrings` (with `s`), you try to use `$finalstring` (without `s`).

Comment: Ups!! Sorry, I'm so tired right now. I apologize for this.